# Can someone explain respond_to? :each?

Tags: ruby

Can someone help me understand the following code?

```
array = [1,2,3,4];
if array.respond_to? :each
  puts "1234"
else
  puts "5678"
end
```

I can understand the result of the code, but what is the syntax of `:each`?

Is `:each` a global method? Why can we write it like this? Or how I can find out about it?

Answer (score 8):

`:each` is a `Symbol`, which is kind of like a `String` but more limited, and more efficient in comparisons for equality. It is *not* a method; it does happen to be a method *name*.

`respond_to?` is a method defined on `Object`, which (almost) all Ruby objects ultimately inherit from.

When you say `[1, 2, 3, 4].each`, it will send the message `:each` to the `Array` object `[1, 2, 3, 4]`. The `Array` class object is aware that its instances will know what to do when they receive such a message, and thus `Array.respond_to?(:each)` return `true`. Basically, if `array.respond_to?(:each)` is `false`, then `array.each` will raise an error. [Note that, as p11y notes in comments, if `array` is really an `Array`, then this will always return `true`. But programmers can lie, and `array` does not have to be an `Array`; for example: `array = "not an Array, fooled you!"`]

`[1, 2, 3, 4].respond_to? :each` is equivalent to `[1, 2, 3, 4].respond_to?(:each)`.

On a side note, semicolons are only ever required in Ruby if you want to stuff several statements on one line. Unlike in C, for example, where semicolon is a statement *terminator*, in Ruby it is statement *separator*. It is thus bad style to write `array = [1, 2, 3, 4];`.

Comment: +1 you explained it much better. Side note: the variable `array` is actually poorly named, because it can also contain something different than an Array, hence the check.

Comment: thank you a ton! feeling much better now~! :D also, I see some doc saying that if we define a String like:

Comment: thank you a ton! feeling much better now~! :D also, what about this : if array.respond_to? ("each"); is this the same as (:each)? I am just thinking about will this "each" create many String objects?

Comment: No, `:each` is not the same as `"each"`; but they can be converted to the other: `"each".to_sym == :each`, and `:each.to_s == "each"`. (Also, you can try for yourself in `irb`.)